# Is the span closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, hamel-basis

Let X be a normed space. Let $v_1, v_2... v_n$ be vectors in X. When is $Span({v_1, v_2, ... v_n})$ closed?

This question is motivated by a question which I had on a problem sheet (this wasn't the exact topic of the question but a required assumption for the proof), which said a span of finite set of vectors from a Hamel Basis of a Banach Space is closed. I'm not sure why that is and I'm not sure in general when the Span is closed, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always is. That span, endowed with the restricted norm, is a finite-dimensional normed space, and therefore it's bi-Lipschitz isomorphic to $\Bbb R^k$ for some $k\le n$. Therefore the restricted metric is complete. A subspace of a metric space for which the restricted metric is complete is necessarily closed.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for the reply!